# How to schedule a script to be run as soon as the system is booted?

Tags: scripts, schedule

My laptop's touchpad doesn't work unless I enter the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

I could do this everytime I log in, but I want to automate it.

How would I go about doing that?

Note the need for my password to run the commands? Any way to avoid saving the password in plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not be done by a script. You can achieve your goal by

```
echo "options psmouse proto=imps" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf
```

Do it once and your touchpad will work after reboot.

But you can get your touchpad working a normal way too.

If you decide to install an Elantech driver, you will have to revert this setting. It can be done by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf
```

Comment: Thanks Pilot.  Can you elaborate on how to get my touchpad to work "a normal way"?

Comment: I answered your other question. But you did not accept it, did not say if that worked but wrote SOLVED in the title.

Comment: With this imps you will not have multitouch. Just read my answer to that question. It gives a normal solution.

Comment: Sorry, I did not try the solution you proposed because I found the quick one which I added to the top of my question.  However, this question is about scheduling.

Comment: I gave you the correct solution to do same. Module options should not be set by a script. There is another way of doing this.

Comment: But this way you will not have scrolling or other gestures.